# Magento templates, changing class names

Tags: css

I'm not sure if this is the best forum to ask this in, but I need to style a magento theme and I'm just wondering how dependent is the javascript on the class names?

For example, I have something like this in my template file (inside my theme file, overriding the base)

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
        <div class="block-content">
            <div class="form-subscribe-header">
```

If I say, leave the ids alone, but change the class names to something else (i.e. remove "block content" or "form-subscribe-header") will this break the javascript in Magento?

Also, is there an easy way to tell if I've broken something? Will I just get a console error if a piece of javascript was coupled with a css class name?

Answer (score 0):

Search your javascript files for your class names to see if they are used by the script. You could also just leave your classes as they are but add a new one in, like this:

```
<div class="form-subscribe-header new-class">
```

Then target the class using `.new-class`

And yes, any javascript errors will appear in the console.

Comment: Like I guess, part of the question too is "Where are the CORE javascript files"...just in the root .js folder?

Comment: @redconservatory That depends on your theme and setup. It's best to check the network/resources section of your console, which will show you all the js files loaded by the website.